# how to add option value in dropdown/ default dropdown value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

```
   var EmpPreviousChart = (from m in dataContext.ViewName
                             where ((m.EmployeeID == Id)&&(m.Status=='C'))
                             orderby m.EmployeeID descending
                             select m.EmployeeID + "- " + m.JoinDate.ToString());

ViewData["EmpPreviousChartList"] = EmpPreviousChart;
```

The above code I am using to retrieve data using linq.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("EmpPreviousCharts", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["EmpPreviousChartList"]), "Select", new { style = "width:60px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px;",  ID = "EmpPrevCharts" })%>
```

the above code to fill my dropdown, I m getting select in very first place. Now I want that the value that should be visible after loading the dropdown should be next to select.
ie If I had select,A,B,C resp. I want A to be visible. I m using partialview for this.
If I could add an **autoincrement field** in option value I can achive it
or if there is any other way out

Answer (score 1):

`SelectList` takes the currently selected item as one of the parameters - just pass the item you want to be selected.

You should be instantiating `SelectList` in your controller, and then pass it to the view. The view should have as little logic as possible.

```
var EmpPreviousChart = (from m in dataContext.ViewName
                             where ((m.EmployeeID == Id)&&(m.Status=='C'))
                             orderby m.EmployeeID descending
                             select m.EmployeeID + "- " + m.JoinDate.ToString()).ToList();

ViewData["EmpPreviousChartList"] = new SelectList(EmpPreviousChart, EmpPreviousChart.FirstOrDefault());


<%= Html.DropDownList("EmpPreviousCharts", (SelectList)ViewData["EmpPreviousChartList"], "Select", new { style = "width:60px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px;",  ID = "EmpPrevCharts" })%>
```

Comment: @Evostract - there is a known issue with DropDownList extension method: make sure that you don't have an item in the ViewBag / property on your model that has the same name as the ID of your select.

Comment: I have pasted the code there nothing else apart from this I m using

Comment: @Evostract - verify in the debugger that SelectList gives you an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` with the first item having `Selected` property set to `true`. You might want to create a blank view and just try it out on a simpler example.